# Is disambiguation via typedefs non-standard behavior in C++?

Tags: c++, standards

[In another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8982983/368599), in one of the comments, I was informed that this *may* be non-standard behavior (especially moving up the hierarchy):

```
struct f1
{
  int operator() (int a, int b) const { return a + b; }
};

struct f2
{
  int operator() (int a, int b) const { return a * b; }
};

struct f3 : f2
{
  typedef f2  base_type;
  int operator() (int a, int b) const 
  { return base_type::operator()(a,b) * (a / b); }
};

struct f4
{
  int operator() (int a, int b) const { return a - b; }
};

struct f5 : f4
{
  typedef f4  base_type; 
  int operator() (int a, int b) const 
  { return base_type::operator()(a,b) * a * b; }
};

template <typename F1, typename F3, typename F5>
class foo : F1, F3, F5 
{
  typedef F1    base_type_1;
  typedef F3    base_type_3;
  typedef F5    base_type_5;

public:
  int f1(int a, int b) { return base_type_1()(a, b); }
  int f3(int a, int b) { return base_type_3()(a, b); }
  int f5(int a, int b) { return base_type_5()(a, b); }

  int f3f2(int a, int b) 
  { 
    return base_type_3::base_type::operator()(a, b) * 
           base_type_3::operator()(a, b);
  }

  int f5f4(int a, int b)
  { 
    return base_type_5::base_type::operator()(a, b) * 
           base_type_5::operator()(a, b);
  }
};

int main()
{
  foo<f1, f3, f5> f;
  f.f1(1,2);
  f.f3(1,4);
  f.f5(1,5);

  f.f3f2(1, 1);
  f.f5f4(2, 2);

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** This compiles under VC++ 2008, no warnings at level 4.

Comment: Can you reference the other question or provide a little info about why they said that so we at least know what to consider?

Comment: Well, it's over my head - +1 for the interesting question though I'll look forward to the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the case wasn't clear in ISO/IEC 14882:2003. Although it says:

```
3.4.31/1 Qualified name lookup
...
If the name found is not a class-name (clause 9) or namespace-name (7.3.1),
the program is ill-formed.
```

there is still an open question of what constitutes a *class-name*:

```
9 Classes
Class-specifiers and elaborated-type-specifiers (7.1.5.3) are used to make class-names.
```

... and if you look up 7.1.5.3, *elaborated-type-specifiers* seem to include dependant names, but without explicitly allowing `typedef` keyword. It *seems* like unintended omission in version 2003 of the standard. Circumstantial evidence: Comeau Compiler in strict mode without C++0x extensions enabled accepts your code.

However, using dependant names this way was explicitly made valid in ISO/IEC 14882:2011. Here is relevant wording:

```
3.4.3/1 Qualified name lookup
...
If a :: scope resolution operator in a nested-name-specifier is not preceded
by a decltype-specifier, lookup of the name preceding that :: considers only 
namespaces, types, and templates whose specializations are types.
If the name found does not designate a namespace or a class, enumeration, or
dependent type, the program is ill-formed.
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, this was a context where the 98 standard prevented the use of typedef-name (I don't have my copy handy to check) while the 2011 standard seems to allow it (the grammar production uses type-name here and the definition of type-name allows typedef-name, and I didn't found additional text preventing its use in this case).